# Best Way to share content across a UK and USA website

Tags: views

I am creating a website that will have a US and UK section and we are going to separate the two via the addresses ....com/uk and ....com/us.

Some of the content will be the same and some of it will differ.  The menu structure will also differ.

The site is relatively small and about half of the content will be shared between the two and half of it will be unique.

We have had had a look at the language/internationalisation modules and they seem a little bit overkill for our needs.

It seems that the best way to achieve this for the shared content is to have a "Shared Page" content type that is never seen, but then a View that accepts a contextual filter in the url (the title) which displays the body of the node at both uk/title and us/title.

However I read somewhere that it is not a good idea to use views to display only a single node and that they should be used only for lists etc.

Is this the case?  If so what method should I use if I want to display a single node at two locations?

Answer (score 3):

We have successfully done this with a multi site installation and the [domain module](http://drupal.org/project/domain).

Comment: We've also used the Domain Access module with success for a similar project.

Comment: Ditto.  This is what Domain Access was designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I use Views every now and then to pull out just a single piece of content (node), and I've suffered no ill effects from it. If the Views solution that you describe is enough for you, then I would go for it.

Some will probably tell you that you this is "bad for performance", but doubt that can be backup up with numbers. I have seen situations where such usage becomes *part* of a performance problem, but that was the front page of a site, with a 3x3 grid of such Views, and they could have been cached better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how does the site search respond to this though, you would no longer be able to search for the node in question.

Comment: I fail to see how displaying a node through a View will affect your search index.